# Material UI - Wipe away all styles

Tags: css, reactjs, styling, material-ui

Is there any way to completely override all material-ui styles and have components adhere to your own completely custom style guide? In essence, wiping all material-ui styles and starting from their html skeletons? Creating a new theme with mui or themeProvider for material-ui components isn't robust enough.

I've looked @ material-ui source code and they have a styles.root variable. Is there was a way to access that object and make it more robust? I'm open to any ideas and recommendations.

---

So far what hasn't worked is:

- themeManager
- muiTheme
- inline styles ( you can't access the child elements of the components )
- class styles ( you have to use !important with a lot of the css attributes and we're trying to avoid that )

Comment: What will be left of the material look if you wipe away all the styles? Sounds like you'd be better off creating custom components.

Comment: @lux All the material-ui interactions, documentation, and support/community is extremely useful: we just want the components to look very different and maintain their functionality. 

But you're right, we've talked about that too, and it's looking more and more likely that it's the route we'll have to take. I'm just making sure that there aren't any alternative solutions before we build a completely bespoke library

Comment: Gotcha, I've only been able to override the muiTheme via the ThemeManager, but haven't seems case where the styles themselves were completely removed. You might have luck posting this on their github issues page as well.

Comment: Thanks @lux! I'll post to that and see what they have to say

Comment: It sounds like this is an extensive enough change that you may want to fork the source code and replace the default style CSS/JS code with an empty style. For example for the `Button` component, just replace the styles object with an object where all the keys are the same but the value is just an empty object `{}`: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/next/packages/material-ui/src/Button/Button.js#L11

Answer (score 0):

> In essence, wiping all material-ui styles and starting from their html skeletons

Material UI doesn't use seperate CSS. All CSS is driven by JS so your only option is what is offered by ThemeManager.

Comment: Yea that's what I was worried about, that the only available changes would be within the constraints of ThemeManager, thanks @basarat!